# spacy - sentence split on docs + gold

Tags: python, spacy

My goal is to sentencize documents which have already been tokenized and matched with gold annotations.

I have a dataset of annotated documents in the classic spacy format

```
{
   "text": "This is a sentence, this is another sentence...",
   "entities": [(100, 112, "PERSON"), (150, 154, "LOCATION"),...]
}
```

and I have transformed it into a BILUO-tagged dataset where the above sample would look like this

```
{
    "text": "This is a sentence, this is another sentence...",
    "spacy_tokens": ["This", "is", "a", "sentence", ",", "this",...],
    "ner_tags": ["O", "O", ..., "B-PERSON", "I-PERSON", "L-PERSON",...]
}
```

using the following code

```
        nlp = spacy.load('de_core_news_sm')
        
        for i, (doc, gold) in enumerate(zip(docs, golds)):
            doc = nlp.make_doc(doc)
            gold = GoldParse(doc, **gold)
            sample = {
                "text": str(doc),
                "tokens": [w for w in doc],
                "ner_tags": [tag for tag in gold.ner]
            }
```

***Question***

My question is how I can now (retrospectively) split the samples further down by sentences. I.e. when I add a `sentencizer` to the spacy pipeline, I can split the `doc` but how do I sync the `gold.sent_starts` with the sentence splits?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your `spacy_tokens` are in sync with your `ner_tags`*, then you need to construct a doc with exactly this tokenization and run it through the sentencizer to get the `token.is_sent_start` values:

```py
import spacy
from spacy.tokens import Doc

nlp = spacy.blank("en")
nlp.add_pipe(nlp.create_pipe("sentencizer"))

text = "He doesn't like London and Berlin. I do."
words = ["He", "doesn't", "like", "London", "and", "Berlin", ".", "I", "do", "."]
ner = ["O", "O", "O", "U-LOC", "O", "U-LOC", "O", "O", "O", "O"]

words, spaces = spacy.util.get_words_and_spaces(words, text)
doc = Doc(nlp.vocab, words=words, spaces=spaces)
doc = nlp.get_pipe("sentencizer")(doc)
sent_starts = [t.is_sent_start for t in doc]
```

If you don't construct the doc by providing the gold tokenization with `Doc(words=)`, the default `English` tokenization for `nlp(text)` would be `['He', 'does', "n't", 'like', 'London', 'and', 'Berlin', '.', 'I', 'do', '.']` and all the `sent_start` (or other) tags would be out of sync.

---

* The code above is fine for only `text` + character offset `entities`, but if your `gold` includes `words`, then `gold.ner` is aligned with `gold.words` but not necessarily with `[t.text for t in doc]`.